# Magento hierarchical attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches, attribute-set, visibility

Does anyone know how to make product attributes visible only when they exist?

Ex. you have a T-shirt, models are Spiderman and Thor (model attribute), and available on red, blue and green (color attribute).

Let's say that Spiderman is available in red and blue.
               Thor is available in blue and green.

How to make color picking available to customers only **after** picking the model?
Also, how to get rid of the crossed out values, instead making only the available colors appear in the store?

Thanks in advance :)